# sorting array using inner array in numbers in php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sorting

I am having one array like this,

array[0][0],[1][0],[2][0] are questions and array[0][1],[1][1],[2][1] are the answers to that questions.
Now i want to sort this array with respect to number of answers.
1st Ques having only one answer and 
2nd having two answer and 3rd having three answer.
The sorted array should be in descending order with respect to number of answers to that question.
Is there anyway to achieve this in sql?  Or how Can we sort in php?  Hope my question is clear.  Thank you in advance.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 110
                    [2] => Tom
                    [3] => Tom@gmail.com
                    [4] => Hello tom how are you?
                    [5] => 2013-01-03 14:54:07
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine.
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 110
                    [2] => Tom
                    [3] => Tom@gmail.com
                    [4] => Hello tom how are you.
                    [5] => 2013-01-03 14:54:07
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 110
                    [2] => Tom
                    [3] => Tom@gmail.com
                    [4] => Hello tom how are you.
                    [5] => 2013-01-03 14:54:07
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => Yes i am fine
                            [2] => Arun
                            [3] => arun@gmail.com
                            [4] => 2013-01-03 14:55:22
                        )
                )
        )
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do with this?

Comment: sorting questions in descending order to show the users with maximum number of answers in first. Are you clear with my question?

Comment: When you export data to SO, it's best to use `var_export`, that way people can just copy the data you provided to test with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return count($a[1]) > count($b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($data, 'cmp');
```

Or if you are using `PHP 5.3.0` or greater, you can use:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return count($a[1]) > count($b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: +1 - Thankyou Supericy.  Its working fine.  It takes more time for me to understand and test your answer.